# Using Google.Cloud.ArtifactRegistry.V1Beta2 with parent - Permission problem

Tags: google-artifact-registry

I wonder if anyone has used Google.Cloud.ArtifactRegistry.V1Beta2?

I am trying to create a console application with the api to list all Repositories in a project.

```
        ListRepositoriesRequest request = new ListRepositoriesRequest
        {
            Parent = "",
            PageSize = 1
        
        };
        var response = client.ListRepositories( request );
```

I have no indication what parent should be. The help just says "The name of the parent resource whose repositories will be listed". I have tried project name, project id but nothing works. I get the error "Permission denied" and I have full access as I am the owner of the project. Being lost what could be wrong, I suspect it could be the parent or does anyone has any idea where to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.locations.repositories/list) are not very clear but this one is very clear. If you look closer to the section **HTTP request** you will find

```
GET https://artifactregistry.googleapis.com/v1beta2/{parent=projects/*/locations/*}/repositories
```

So the parent is:

```
{parent=projects/*/locations/*} -> projects/*/locations/*
```

So, if you want to list repositories in `us-central1` for example, your parent will be:

```js
ListRepositoriesRequest request = new ListRepositoriesRequest
        {
            Parent = "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1",
            PageSize = 1
        
        };
        var response = client.ListRepositories( request );
```

So my advice is to inspect very well the docs.